PyCharm loading ssh conda environment takes forever
I am using PyCharm SSH to work on a server. I am now stuck at setting up an interpreter for my Project.
Note that I didn't create a project and use an ssh interpreter. Instead, I chose Remote Development - SSH in the PyCharm wizard.

When I am configuring my interpreter, I tried to add an existing conda environment. I specified the path to conda executable and clicked on "reload environments" to load the conda env list. Under normal circumstances, the env list should load quickly and I should be able to choose en env from the dropdown. However, PyCharm is stuck at the "Reload environment" process.

How should I do to solve this?

When I was configuring my interpreter, I clicked on "add local interpreter" and produced the problem in the question description. As far as I am concerned, once I connect to SSH in Remote Development mode, the interpreter on my server should be treated as a "local" interpreter.
I was able to figure out a workaround by choosing "add SSH interpreter" instead. I still don't quite understand why the interpreter should count as an "SSH interpreter" since I have already connected to SSH in remote development mode. But it works

Please provide more information on how and why this approach works. The answer as written answers an environment setup.

@LokeshA.R. The question is about environment setup. I just described the problem I had and how I managed to solve it. The reason behind this is unknown to me. This looks like a bug of PyCharm.
